How to create two surfaces sloped into two directions?
I'm trying to build two surfaces like shown in the figure. Both surfaces are sloped into two directions. The side that remains flat needs to be around 51 studs long (see picture). It is therefore hard to do it with regular sloped plates like a 12x3 (47397). I tried several things with jumping sloped bricks, but of all the bricks the slopes are too intense to achieve a good result over this length.
Does anyone have any good suggestions for building techniques that would work for this. I've been stuck on this for a while.



You say the longer side is about 52 studs, but how wide should the surface be?

I just added a new picture, indicating the surfaces and the dimensions.

Ah, it seems I have completely misinterpreted the 3D angles.

For such gentle slopes I would try using the rigid pneumatic pipe parts: you can mount them by both ends of the building at specific heights to form lengthwise chords and use plates with clips to affix tiles or plates to them across that would become the surface.
See this tablescrap for how it could work and how it would look like:


Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Indeed a nice technique to create a slope over a longer distance! I will try to make a sketch with the remaining dimensions of the surface later this week, if I have time.
